# How to override class-wc-gateway-bacs.php file in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a problem regarding overriding the file in woocommerce/includes/gateways/bacs/class-wc-gateway-bacs.php

I have edited this file and added some other fields and changed placement order. I have tried the following locations in an attempt to use my version:

- mytheme/woocommerce/includes/gateways/bacs/class-wc-gateway-bacs.php
- mytheme/woocommerce/includes/gateways/class-wc-gateway-bacs.php
- mytheme/woocommerce/includes/bacs/class-wc-gateway-bacs.php

None of the above locations worked. In my previous job I successfully overrode some of the files in woo-commerce by placing overloads within the /templates/ folder to do the trick but this time it is more complicated.

I didn't want to replace the original file to prevent my custom edits being overwritten when the plugin is updated.

Is there's a way to override it?

Answer (score 3):

Hi Mosak i think you are working on the wrong side. Due to extend Woocommerce payment gateways you cannot override the plugin classes working on templates but you should create your own plugin hooking your code to the filter used by woocommerce to recognize the registered payment gateways.

```
add_action('plugins_loaded', 'init_my_gateway_class');

function init_my_gateway_class() {
    add_filter('woocommerce_payment_gateways', 'add_this_class_to_gateway_class');

    /**
    * @param array $methods
    * @return string
    */
    function add_this_class_to_gateway_class($methods){
        $methods[] = 'WC_My_Gateway';
        return $methods;
    }

    class WC_My_Gateway extends WC_Payment_Gateway{
       /**
        * Here you can create your own payment gateway
        * defining the specs on the constructor.
        **/
    }
}
```

The class WC_My_Gateway, hypothetically, could be your customization of the original bacs class, mantaining compatibility and leaving the original bacs class active.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you gadz82 I will work on this now.. I will back soon if there was a problem. thanks again..

Comment: can you take a look what's wrong with my code? it seems not working & not override the file that I was working on. 

https://gist.github.com/mosak2k12/20189641e05e085c1ee7

my main reason is that I had an additional array fields for the bacs account details & renaming the labels. so my only option is to override the file within my template and not touching the core of the plugin.